# Plotting multiple figures from one excel file using pandas and matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am working with a rather large excel file (over million rows). I want to plot 720 rows and then skip 43609 rows and then plot the next 720 to a different figure. Is there a way to do this without having to read the file before every plot and still be able to use skiprows?

Comment: Please post a dummy dataframe with code and expected output.

Comment: What have you tried, why did it fail? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a minimal, complete, and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Possible solution is to use `lambda function` in `skiprows` parameter of `pd.read_excel` and the slices to create plots from required rows.

For example you would like to skip yellow rows in the excel file that looks like:

[image]

```
# pip install pandas

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx', header=0, skiprows = lambda x: x in range(6, 11))
df
```

[image]

Then you can use slices to create plots.

```
plt.plot(df[:4])
plt.plot(df[5:])

plt.show()
```

[image]